# Unset the Canonical Tag in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am attempting to unset the canonical tag from the head of drupal 7.
I have output the head elements in template.php using:

```
function mytemplatename_html_head_alter(&$head_elements) {
  print_r($head_elements);
}
```

which has given me the following for the canonical tag:

```
  [drupal_add_html_head_link:canonical:</node/1>;] => Array
        (
            [#tag] => link
            [#attributes] => Array
                (
                    [rel] => canonical
                    [href] => /node/1
                )

            [#attached] => Array
                (
                    [drupal_add_http_header] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Link
                                    [1] => </node/1>; rel="canonical"
                                    [2] => 1
                                )

                        )

                )

            [#type] => html_tag
        )
```

I assumed I could just use the html_head_alter hook to unset it but the following will not work:

```
function grocore_html_head_alter(&$head_elements) {
  unset($head_elements['drupal_add_html_head_link:canonical']);
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
unset($head_elements['drupal_add_html_head_link:canonical:</node/1>;']);
```

or for every path

```
foreach (preg_grep('/^drupal_add_html_head_link:canonical:</', array_keys($head_elements)) as $key) {
  unset($head_elements[$key]);
}
```